# watermark that is deleted first on keypress?

Tags: jquery

is there a watermark jquery plugin that dont delete the watermark text when the text is in focus but deletes the watermark text first when the user is typing something in it?

then the watermark will still be visible when the first text field is automatically selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be easy to manipulate if you can't find the exact plugin that you're looking for. For example, [this plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/watermark-input-plugin/) has the following as the actual clearMessage event:

```
input.focus(clearMessage);
input.blur(insertMessage);  
input.change(insertMessage);
```

Which you could just alter to say this:

```
input.keypress(clearMessage);
input.blur(insertMessage);  
input.change(insertMessage);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a jQuery plugin for this called Watermarkify. It not only displays watermarks but also animates them on focus.

Demo:

http://www.ajaybalachandran.com/demo/watermarkify/

Download:

http://www.ajaybalachandran.com/blog/48/watermarkify-jquery-twitter-like-animated-textfield-watermarks/

Answer (score 0):

i have the best and easiest solution for this problem

```
<input value="" placeholder="watermark text:" />
```